# How to add <noscript> tags to headlink()->appendStylesheet() in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using a plugin that has a noscript tag, which is an alternative for browsers that have javascipt disabled. [-source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)

The code I am using in the action is:

```
$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/my.css');
```

However this just appends it as is, I would like the script to be within a `<noscript></noscript>` tag.

The docs says:

```
appendStylesheet($href, $media, $conditionalStylesheet, $extras)
```

But I am still unsure how I would go about this?

Answer (score 1):

According to my assumption dude ...
Don't go for the hardest thing.
    Just type the code

```
<noscript>
    <div>
        <h4>Warning!</h4>
        <p>You need to have <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">JavaScript</a> enabled to use this site.</p>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for better solution.

`echo $this->view->layout()->scriptTags = '<noscript>No Javascript</noscript>';`

Answer (score 0):

Try Healink helper to add inline javascript in to your view

please refer [AppendScript](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html) with detail

```
<?php  $this->headScript()->appendScript('<noscript></noscript>', 
    $type = 'text/javascript') ?>
```

hope this will sure work for you.